# How to filter nested json data

Tags: javascript

I have a json data of this format:

```
[
  {'name':'foo1','id':'1'},
  {'name':'foo2','id':'2',children:[
                                   {'name':'foo3','id':'3',children:
                                           [
                                            {'name':'foo4','id':'4'}
                                           ]
                                   },
                                  ]
  },
  {'name':'foo','id':'1'},
]
```

I want to remove the children array from `foo3` with name `foo4`. and return an whole array without that children.

Lets say : i have a name `foo4` , based on this value, i want to remove the object from the children key.

**before filter**:

```
{'name':'foo3','id':'3',children:
                                           [
                                            {'name':'foo4','id':'4'}
                                           ]
                                   },
```

**After Filter** :

```
 { 'name':'foo3','id':'3',children:[] },
```

This json object can have infinite nested children. I cant figure it out how can i filter the array. Is the recursion best fit here?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please? Because the question starts off with a very specific issue 'delete children containing foo4 from foo3' but later the behaviour of the fix should be rather dynamic as you have infinite nested children? What should be deleted when exactly?

Comment: If you cannot retrieve easily the data you want to delete, maybe this is not the best structure to represent your data?

Comment: On "infinite" nesting levels do you want to delete everything from the lowest level or everything starting from level 2 downwards?

Comment: @Botimoo i just want to delete everything starting from level 2 downwards

Comment: @NicoVanBelle i am working on the nested drag and drop menu in angular2. And the situtation is when i want to delete the menu that is already added to my menu .But this menu is multilevel in depth. What should i do to remove the last child element from the menu. my data structure is same as in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove the children array in your array as you said it will come in many arrays. 
what you have to do is that in javascript/or in any server side lang you can check this condition if your array has children array then do nothing.

Comment: But i need to filter the array based on the name and remove that particular object from the original array.

Comment: Okay buddy. I think you want to do this like i've done on jsfiddle .

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to remove everything from level 2 downwards, I don't think recursion is the way to go. You should just check the children of each object and if they have children of their own, simply remove them.

```js
var data = [
  {'name':'foo1','id':'1'},
  {'name':'foo2','id':'2',children:[
     {'name':'foo3','id':'3',children:
       [
        {'name':'foo4','id':'4'}
       ]
     },
    ]
  },
  {'name':'foo6','id':'6',children:[
     {'name':'foo7','id':'7',children:
       [
        {'name':'foo8','id':'8',children: [
            {'name':'foo9','id':'9'}
          ]
        }
       ]
     },
    ]
  },
  {'name':'foo','id':'1'},
];

var filteredData = data;
for(var i = 0; i < filteredData.length; ++i) {
  var object = filteredData[i];
  if(object.children) {
    //the object has property 'children'
    
    for(var j = 0; j < object.children.length; ++j) {
      var child = object.children[j];
      if(child.children) {
        //the child has children of its own
        child.children = [];
      }
    }
  }
}
console.log(filteredData);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a function that takes an object array and empties the children array whenever x levels deep (parameter `maxDepth`), using recursion.
I use currying to keep track of the levels (`xDeep`) per recursion for all objects.

```js
function removeDeepChildren(data, maxDepth) {
  var xDeep = 1;
  return function innerRecurring(arr) {
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
      if (arr[x].children) {
        if (xDeep === maxDepth && arr[x].children) {
          arr[x].children = [];
        } else {
          ++xDeep;
          innerRecurring(arr[x].children);
        }
      }
    }
  }(data);
}

var data = [{'name':'foo1','id':'1'},{'name':'foo2','id':'2','children':[{'name':'foo3','id':'3','children':[{'name':'foo4','id':'4'}]}]},{'name':'foo','id':'1'}];

removeDeepChildren(data, 2);

console.log(data);
```